# Powershell command: resetting a counter for naming files

Tags: powershell

I have a thousand jpg file in a folder.

I use the following command to name these files as:

file-0, file-1, file-2, file-3, ....

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("file-{0}.jpg" -f $nr++)}
```

However, when I run this command again, all the files are named as

file-1001, file-1002, file-1003, file-1004....

Is there a way to reset the increment counter, so if I run the command again, the names correspond to file-0, file-1, file-2, file-3, ....?

Comment: I just setup a "New folder on desktop" 4 folders inside and ran the same code you have used from inside the New folder and it changed them all - file-0.jpg , file-1.jpg etc ?

Comment: Why not just set you own counter variable and increment in code? Of course then you can do whatever you choose to reset it.

Comment: @mic84 What happen if you ran the same code again immediately after? Or ran the same code for a different folder after that you have ran it for the first one?

Comment: @Håkon You can reset the counter by running `$nr = 0`, or if you're running the code from a script simply define the counter variable with a value of 0 in the beginning of the script.

Comment: @FastEthernet Thanks. Im not familiar with powershell scripting